# Call r 'deparse substitute' in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Not sure I am implementing the best solution, by calling r here.  I would like an S4 object, created in Rcpp, to hold a representation to the data used to create it.  I am under the impression that c++ generally doesn't like such behavior.  The simple example below calls r deparse(substitute()), but gives the vector as a string instead of the vector's name.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::S4 getname_cpp(NumericVector x) {
  
  Rcpp::S4 out("Thing");
  
  Rcpp::Function f("getname");
  
  out.slot("name") = f(x);
  
  return out;
}


/*** R
getname <- function(obj){
  return(deparse(substitute(obj), nlines = 1))
}

setClass("Thing", slots = c(name = "character") )

myvec <- 1:10
getname_cpp(myvec)
*/
```

Comment: In C++ `x` is just a numeric vector. With `substitute` you are trying to access the R call. Your C++ function currently has no access to the R call. I don't know if and how this would be possible.

Comment: If I 'Rcpp::Rcout << f(x)' I get the c or c++ reference to the 1:10 vector, something like '0x7fe662901678'.  The question then becomes can r retrieve the variable name from the reference?

Comment: I don't see how. As I said, you need to access the call, not the vector in memory.

Comment: Rephrasing your question as "The Rcpp headers do not include the entire R engine" I would have to nod and say "Yup".  @Roland is spot on, you are demanding something from your design it is not set up to deliver. I fear you may need to rethink what each language is best at.

Comment: Getting names from named vector, in case that is what you want, is much easier: you just access the attribute via `names()` or via the attribute setter/getter.  This Rcpp Gallery shows how to [in this piece](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/setting-object-attributes/).